# ionic 4 + angular 7 Reactive Form with Validators HTML rendering issue

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I'm pretty new to ionic and angular and I'm trying to learn by tutorials.

Following a tutorial on how to make a login form using **Reactive Forms**, I'm facing the following issue: when I declare a Validator for a FormControl (input box) in the FormBuilder, the frontend shows a javascript function rendered inside the textbox (in place of showing the placeholder text).

Here below the code for the controller, the view, my environment configuration and what I get on the GUI.
It might be a version/dependencies problem?
How can I fix or update the dependencies version without breaking everything?
Or simply I've found a framework bug?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards.

---

Controller code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      email: new FormControl(Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl(Validators.compose([
         // no code here and it works fine, if I add a validator it breaks
      ]))
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    console.log('email: ' + this.loginForm.value.email);
    console.log('password: ' + this.loginForm.value.password);
  }
}
```

View code:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>login</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
  
<ion-content padding>

  <form [formGroup]='loginForm'>

    <ion-input class="form-control" formControlName="email" type="text" ></ion-input>

    <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" ></ion-input>
  
    <ion-button (click)="login()" size="large" expand="block">Login</ion-button>
  
    <ion-button size="large" expand="block" router-direction="forward">Register</ion-button>

  </form>

</ion-content>
```

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.2
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 7
```

Code rendered inside the input box

```
function (control) {
   return isEmptyInputValue(control.value) ? { 'required': true } : null;
}
```

[image: GUI rendered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email    : ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  password : ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
})
```

Check the guide here:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-making-a-field-required

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it's done in Ionic, but iconic does use Angular, so this could work.

```
password: new FormControl('Default Value', [Validators.compose([Validator.required]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change this line `password: new FormControl(Validators.compose([]))` to `password: new FormControl()` or `password: new FormControl(Validators.required)`